# External Sony Hard Disk cannot be accessed

Tags: hard-drive

As the title says, my system cannot read/accessed external Hard Disk. I tried with all the ports many times (including SATA) but failed. Microsoft Windows is asking to format it (so I can use it) but I would not want to atleast now. I can see the hard drive in the 'device manager' and 'My Computer' with the drive name. I also tried by changing the drive letter from H to any letter from 'diskmgmt.msc'. While doing so, I see the file system is RAW ( It was NTFS), Primary Partition shows 931.51 GB and properties shows '0 Bytes used' & '0 Bytes Free Space'. As for the device, the blue light glows and beeps while injected/ejected. Is there anyway to retrieve all the data contents (used space atleast 550 GB) from it? #SonyHardDisk Please help as the data meant so much to me. (Noise from the HDD can clearly be heard as if it would work). If you need any more info, I'll let you know. Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Do you hear unusual noise coming from HDD?

Comment: That sounds like something has ripped the MBR/GPT MFT apart

Comment: #TD.512 What do I do? Replace it? What 'bout the data?

Comment: #Jet Yes, clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to share this. Open a cmd prompt window, I typed chkdsk x: /f where x is the letter name assigned to drive, waited for 10 secs and loh, it works! Yippie!